# MPI Allreduce - Address is 0 bytes after a block of size 216 alloc'd

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi, valgrind

I'm working on an MPI problem, and I want to use an Allreduce. However, Its throwing a segmentation fault.

When running with valgrind I get the following stacktrace

```
==1081== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1081== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1081== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1081== Command: ./test
==1081== 
==1081== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1081==    at 0x57D4375: opal_value_unload (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x4E7F97A: ompi_proc_complete_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x4E838A4: ompi_mpi_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x4EA42AA: PMPI_Init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x108CC2: main (test.c:53)
==1081==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==1081==    at 0x4E7F90D: ompi_proc_complete_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081== 
==1081== Invalid read of size 8
==1081==    at 0x4C367EE: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1081==    by 0x57E163F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x1170CEEC: mca_coll_self_allreduce_intra (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_self.so)
==1081==    by 0x4E92479: PMPI_Allreduce (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x108EA3: main (test.c:79)
==1081==  Address 0xfaeaee8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 216 alloc'd
==1081==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1081==    by 0x108B4B: initCells (test.c:34)
==1081==    by 0x108E4B: main (test.c:76)
==1081== 
==1081== Invalid write of size 8
==1081==    at 0x4C367E3: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1081==    by 0x57E163F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x1170CEEC: mca_coll_self_allreduce_intra (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_self.so)
==1081==    by 0x4E92479: PMPI_Allreduce (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x108EA3: main (test.c:79)
==1081==  Address 0xfaeadc8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 216 alloc'd
==1081==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1081==    by 0x108B4B: initCells (test.c:34)
==1081==    by 0x108E3A: main (test.c:75)
==1081== 
==1081== Invalid read of size 8
==1081==    at 0x4C367E0: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1081==    by 0x57E163F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x1170CEEC: mca_coll_self_allreduce_intra (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_self.so)
==1081==    by 0x4E92479: PMPI_Allreduce (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.10.1)
==1081==    by 0x108EA3: main (test.c:79)
==1081==  Address 0xfaeaef8 is 16 bytes after a block of size 216 alloc'd
==1081==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1081==    by 0x108B4B: initCells (test.c:34)
==1081==    by 0x108E4B: main (test.c:76)
==1081== 
==1081== 
==1081== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1081==     in use at exit: 187,536 bytes in 698 blocks
==1081==   total heap usage: 21,481 allocs, 20,783 frees, 4,286,585 bytes allocated
==1081== 
==1081== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1081==    definitely lost: 31,023 bytes in 40 blocks
==1081==    indirectly lost: 2,121 bytes in 60 blocks
==1081==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1081==    still reachable: 154,392 bytes in 598 blocks
==1081==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1081== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1081== 
==1081== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1081== ERROR SUMMARY: 19 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The code is the following

```
File: test.c
01: #include <stdlib.h>
02: #include <stdio.h>
03: #include <time.h>
04: #include <memory.h>
05: #include <mpi.h>
06: #include <stddef.h>
07: #include <math.h>
08: #include <unistd.h>
09: 
10: typedef struct particle_t
11: {
12:     double m;
13:     double x;
14:     double y;
15:     double vx;
16:     double vy;
17:     double fx;
18:     double fy;
19: 
20: } particle_t;
21: 
22: typedef struct centerMass
23: {
24:     double x;
25:     double y;
26:     double totalmass;
27: } centerMass;
28: 
29: int numprocs, my_rank;
30: MPI_Datatype particle_type, old_type;
31: 
32: centerMass *initCells()
33: {
34:     centerMass *gridMasses = (centerMass *)malloc(3 * 3 * sizeof(centerMass));
35:     return gridMasses;
36: }
37: 
38: void reduceMasses(centerMass *in, centerMass *inout, int *len, MPI_Datatype *dtpr)
39: {
40:     for (int i = 0; i < *len; i++)
41:     {
42:         inout[i].totalmass += in[i].totalmass;
43:         inout[i].x += in[i].x;
44:         inout[i].y + in[i].y;
45:     }
46: }
47: 
48: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
49: {
50:     // MPI initializations
51:     MPI_Status status;
52:     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
53:     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
54:     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
55: 
56:     int count = 7;
57:     MPI_Datatype types[] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE};
58:     int blocklengths[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
59:     MPI_Aint displacements[] = {
60:         offsetof(particle_t, m),
61:         offsetof(particle_t, x),
62:         offsetof(particle_t, y),
63:         offsetof(particle_t, vx),
64:         offsetof(particle_t, vy),
65:         offsetof(particle_t, fx),
66:         offsetof(particle_t, fy),
67:     };
68:     MPI_Aint lb, extent;
69:     MPI_Type_create_struct(count, blocklengths, displacements, types, &old_type);
70:     MPI_Type_get_extent(old_type, &lb, &extent);
71:     MPI_Type_create_resized(old_type, lb, extent, &particle_type);
72:     MPI_Type_commit(&particle_type);    
73: 
74:     centerMass *newMasses = initCells();
75:     centerMass *oldMasses = initCells();
76:     MPI_Op rM;
77:     MPI_Op_create(reduceMasses, 1, &rM);
78:     MPI_Allreduce(oldMasses, newMasses, 3 * 3, particle_type, rM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
79: 
80:     MPI_Finalize();
81: }
82: 
83: 
84:
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, because if I comment the Allreduce clause it works. I looked online and this error is usually related to null terminating strings, which I don't use at all.

Thanks

Comment: Lines 53, 75, 76 and 79 are which?

Comment: This "*==1081== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)-32*" looks really strange. Are you sure you are using the most recent *and* stable release?

Comment: @alk Updated with line numbers. I installed openMPI with ```sudo apt install libblacs-mpi-dev```

Comment: @alk I tried running with the latest mpich and have the same result.

Comment: You allocate 27 double, but allreduce on 56 double.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. I always allocate 3x3 positions.

Comment: @ggpfc manually count the `double` you allocate (hint, it is 27) and the data the all reduce operates on (hint, it is 56), once you understand where the mismatch comes from, the fix will be trivial. No spoiler needed imho.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh god it was so simple, I was using the wrong Datatype. Thank you, you can submit it as an answer if you want to :)